# What action should I hook into when adding roles and capabilities?

Tags: capabilities, actions, user-roles

I'm going to be using add_role() and $role->add_cap() to set up a new custom role and attach a new capability to existing roles.

I'm wondering where the best place to do this is? Obviously I can do it straight inside functions.php and be done with it. But is this the best practice? Do I only need to do this on admin_init? or should I do it on init?

I'm not entirely sure what the best practices are around using init action hooks rather than just dropping a direct function call inside functions.php.

thanks for your input!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When adding a role and capabilities you only need to run the code once since the roles and capabilities are saved to the database when using `add_role` or `->add_cap` functions so just like Andy said you can use `after_setup_theme` for this kind of action but add some kind of check so it only runs once, like [register_activation_hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) or using options:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','my_add_role_function');

function my_add_role_function(){
    $roles_set = get_option('my_roles_are_set');
    if(!$roles_set){
        add_role('my_role', 'my_roleUser', array(
            'read' => true, // True allows that capability, False specifically removes it.
            'edit_posts' => true,
            'delete_posts' => true,
            'upload_files' => true 
        ));
        update_option('my_roles_are_set',true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it true that add_role or add_cap ALWAYS leverages the database? When I dug into the source code it seemed this was not always the case - ie: in most of the methods of WP_Roles, there's a check for if ($this->use_db), which makes me think that there is the possibility that roles might not be always stored in the DB.

Comment: Also, rather than setting a flag using options, which doesn't strike me as particularly scalable, is there not a way to simply query whether the role has been created? Failing that, what harm would it do to re-define the role if it's already there? Would you get a duplicate role or would it just ignore? Looking again at capabilities.php I see this under add_role:  if ( isset( $this->roles[$role] ) )
   return; which seems to indicate that it won't duplicate the role so no harm done.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but the defualt is `$use_db = true;` in the WP_Roles class.
and as for setting a flag using options , it is an example, you can use `register_activation_hook` but the idea is that your code would only run once and that way you save yourself the time of excution.

Comment: I've never seen this through, but it strikes me that it might make sense to put role changes into a plugin and then take advantage of the activation/deactivation hooks to trigger the changes just once. Has anyone ever gone down that route?

Comment: @mrwweb that should work just fine as well

Comment: That is a nice solution but `register_activation_hook` would not help for dynamic role adding . In static cases I do see the point . I think what @TomAuger suggested ( do a simple check if exist would be a solution - albeit not an economic one resource and time wise .) I am still looking for a better solution for that myself ..

Comment: @krembo99 if your plugin is adding roles dynamically (ie: as a result of user action), then there's no reason you couldn't just use the basic `add_role()`, since it wouldn't be called every time WordPress loads (assuming that `true == $use_db`). It's more of an issue if a plugin adds base functionality that requires new roles/caps to be created, in which case `register_activation_hook` is a great solution. Where it is still a problem is for `mu-plugins` or bespoke theme-dependent functionality. In that case, commenting out the code after you run it the first time works, though inelegantly.

Answer (score 7):

For plugins, I have had success using `plugins_loaded` for this. For themes, I would use `after_setup_theme`.